# SSAS. How to show images in Excel from OLAP cube's url

Tags: sql, excel, image, ssas, olap

Maybe my title is incorrect but what I need:

I want to show images (not their urls) in excel when browsing cube.

I have stored urls of images in database table, created dimension with data like that:

```
No  LinkToPicture
1   www.example.com/img1.jpg
2   http://www.example.com/img2.jpg
3   \\LOCAL\etc\img3.jpg
```

I've tried many solutions, but nothing worked.

I've tried to change `Type` of `LinkToPicture` attribute to `ImageUrl`, for `KeyColumns`, `NameColumn`, `ValueColumn` have changed `Mime Type` to `image/jpeg`, but nothing worked, have you any ideas how to solve It?

Comment: What version of Excel and what version of SSAS? Multidimensional or Tabular SSAS?

Comment: @GregGalloway Excel 2013 and Multidimensional SSAS.

Comment: if you were using SSAS Tabular you would use Power View sheets in Excel 2013 and it will show images. But Excel 2013 doesn't support Multidimensional models. Excel 2016 does support Multidimensional models. I haven't tried images yet in Power View in Excel 2016 against Multidimensional but expect it would work. I don't know how to show an image in a PivotTable.